# SQL Count Duplicates where field has same month

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to get the count of duplicates of Col `DP` & Col `RN` together where Col `EDate` has a particular month.

I have this which will count all the single occurrences for a month but i can't work out how to revise this to count how many duplicates exist with the particular month.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM (Select DP, RN, EDate, COUNT(*)OVER(PARTITION BY DP, RN) AS your_count
        from ETable) a WHERE your_count = 1 and Month(EDate) = 08) as x
```

Example (trying to count all duplicates of DP & RN together where month is August)

```
DP         RN        EDate
DP1        RP1      2017-08-09     <--yes
DP2        RP1      2017-08-09
DP3        RP1      2017-08-09     <--yes
DP1        RP2      2017-08-09
DP2        RP1      2017-07-09
DP1        RP1      2017-08-09     <--yes
DP3        RP1      2017-08-09     <--yes
```

Result
Count = 2

Comment: Please show us your _exact_ desired output.

Answer (score 3):

Based on clarifications from the original answer, here's a revised answer (with original comment below)

```
select dp, rn, month(edate), count(month(edate))
from table1
where not exists
( 
  select * 
  from table1 t1
  where t1.dp = table1.dp
  and t1.rn = table1.rn
  and month(t1.eDate) <> month(table1.eDate)
)
group by dp, rn, month(edate)
having count(month(edate)) > 1
```

---

How about this?

```
select dp, rn, month(edate), count(month(edate))
from eTable
group by dp, rn, month(edate)
having count(month(edate)) > 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cc9cf/3

The following will also incorporate the year:

```
select dp, rn, format(edate,'MM-yyyy'), count(format(edate,'MM-yyyy'))
from eTable
group by dp, rn, format(edate,'MM-yyyy')
having count(format(edate,'MM-yyyy')) > 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f658b/5

Comment: I need to exclude any DP RN's from the count if one of the duplicates is from another month, is this possible? So with the following i wouldn't want the DP1 RP1 to be included in the count http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f03c2

Comment: Can you explain that a little bit more?

Comment: Do you JUST want the results from August, for example?  You could add a where clause, either "where MONTH(eDate) = 8" or "where MONTH(eDate) = 8 AND YEAR(eDate)=2017"

Comment: So i'm trying to count duplicates only where there date for every row in that duplicate set is of the month i'm after. If any of the rows in the duplicate is outside that date range and then i don't want to count anything from that set. Does that makes sense?

Comment: I think so - see edits in the answer.  I've stopped incorporating the year since you haven't seemed to indicate year is relevant.  I've added a "NOT EXISTS" predicate; this will exclude answers for which the DP/RN pair also has one or more rows with a different month.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to count how many duplicates exist using this query

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN your_count > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
FROM   (SELECT DP, 
               RN, 
               EDate, 
               COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY DP, RN) AS your_count 
        FROM   ETable
        WHERE  Month(EDate) = 08) a
```